# Search broken? It's not returning results

Tags: support

why doesn't this show my latest answers with `CREATE FUNCTION`?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+user%3A2639+%22CREATE+FUNCTION

It has three components,

- `is:answer`
- `user:2639` (me)
- `"CREATE FUNCTION"`

It only returns this answer,

- A: Are there any way to execute a query inside a string value in PostgreSQL?

For example, it does not show

- [How to get the count percentage in 100% of a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222997/how-to-get-the-count-percentage-in-100-of-a-query/223015#223015)
- [Is there any performance advantage to marking a SQL function as LEAKPROOF?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210390/is-there-any-performance-advantage-to-marking-a-sql-function-as-leakproof)
- [procedure for postgres to create table if not exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/procedure-for-postgres-to-create-table-if-not-exist/195559#195559)

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296120 e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+user%3A2639+code%3A%22CREATE+FUNCTION%22 may be helpful

Comment: @PaulWhite https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296120/why-is-code-excluded-from-phrase-search#comment1044604_318638

Comment: You are too funny 

Comment: `code:xxx` should be documented.